# Form redirecionado para uma 2ª página, mas não recebo a informação submetida no email

Tags: php, html, formulário, envio-de-email

Tenho um formulário chamado `formulario.html` que quando é submetido com sucesso, a pessoa é redirecionada para uma página de agradecimentos do site chamada `agradecimentos.html`. Tudo estava a funcionar bem, mas quando vou ao meu email e a um email secundário eu não recebo a informação submetida nesse mesmo formulário.

### Formulario.html:

```html
<form action="suporte_email.php" method="post" name="formulario" id="formulario" >

<div class="row" id="row">
  <div class="esq" id="esq">
  
   
       <div class="conjunto" id="conjunto">
          <label for="MERGE0">Email para Contacto: <span>*</span></label><br>
       <input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="email" id="MERGE0" type="email"></input> 
       </div>
   
       <div class="conjunto1" id="conjunto1">
       <label for="nome">Nome de Contacto: <span>*</span></label><br>
       <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    
   
    <div class="conjunto2" id="conjunto2">
       <label for="empresa">Nome da Empresa: </label><br>
        <input id="empresa" name="empresa" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    
   
    <div class="conjunto3" id="conjunto3">
        <label>Número de Contacto <span>*</span></label><br>
        <input id="contacto" name="contacto" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <br>
   

    <div class="conjunto4" id="conjunto4">
        <label for="marca">Marca do Produto:<span>*</span></label><br>   
     <select multiple name="marca" multiple id="marca"  width="570" style="width:570px;" required>
                 <option value="X">X</option>
                 <option value="Y">Y</option>
                 <option value="Z">Z</option>
                 <option value="E">E</option>
                 <option value="W">W</option>
                 <option value="Q">Q</option>
                 <option value="A">A</option>
                 <option value="S">S</option>
                 <option value="R">R</option>
                 <option value="C">C</option>
                 <option value="C">C</option>
                 <option value="D">D</option>
                 <option value="F">F</option>
                 <option value="G">G</option>
                 <option value="B">B</option>
                 <option value="H">H</option>
                 <option value="N">N</option>
                 <option value="J">J</option>
                 <option value="U">U</option>
                 <option value="I">I</option>
                 <option value="K">K</option>
                 <option value="M">M</option>
                 <option value="Outra">Outra</option>
            </select>
    </div>
   
    
   
    <div class="conjunto5" id="conjunto5">
         <label for="other">Se escolheu "Outra", indique qual:</label><br>
         <input id="other" class="text control" name="other" type="text"> </input>
    </div>
         
   
    <div class="conjunto6" id="conjunto6">
    <label for="serial_number">Número de Série:<span>*</span></label><br>
       <input id="serial_number" name="serial_number" id="serial_number" type="text"></input>
    </div>
   
   </div>
   
   <div class="dir" id="dir">
                             
   
   <div class="conjunto7" id="conjunto7">
    <label for="garantia">Garantia</label><br>
      <div>
   <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio"  value="Sim">
      <label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span> Sim </label>
   </div>
   
   
      <div>
     <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio"  value="Não">
      <label for="radio2"><span><span></span></span> Não </label>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <br><br><br><br>
   
   <div class="conjunto8" id="conjunto8">
    <label for="contrato">Contrato</label><br>
       <div>
      <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  value="Sim">
       <label for="checkbox1"><span></span> Sim </label>
    </div>
          
    <div>
      <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  value="Não">
    <label for="checkbox2"><span></span> Não </label>
    </div>
    
    
   </div>
   
  
   
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div id="separa" class="separa">
   <div class="conjunto9" id="conjunto9">
        <label for="permissoes">Tipo de Suporte:<span>*</span></label><br> 
      <select multiple name="permissoes" multiple id="permissoes" width="570" style="width:570px;" required>
                 <option value="Pedido de Informação Técnica">Pedido de Informação Técnica</option>
                 <option value="Pedido de Assistência Técnica">Pedido de Assistência Técnica</option>
                 <option value="Reclamação Técnica">Reclamação Técnica</option>
                 <option value="Seguimento de Pedido de Informação Técnica">Seguimento de Pedido de Informação Técnica</option>
                 <option value="Seguimento de Pedido de Assistência Técnica">Seguimento de Pedido de Assistência Técnica</option>
            </select>
   </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="conjunto10" id="conjunto10">
      <label for="descricao_avaria">Descrição da Avaria:</label><br>
           <div class="styled" id="styled">  <textarea  name="descricao_avaria" cols="62" rows="10"></textarea> </div>
    </div>
   </div>


<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Tal como disse, `agradecimentos.html` é uma página simples que redireciona a pessoa para uma página de agradecimentos do site.

O código de php correspondente é `suporte_email.php`. O problema é que a informação colocada nesse formulário não é enviada para o email correspondente. E já revi o código do `.php` e não consigo perceber o que se passa.

### suporte_email.php:

```html
<?php
$crlf = "\r\n";
//Get Data
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];                    
    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];              
    $contacto = $_POST['contacto'];            
    $email = $_POST['email'];                  
    $marca = $_POST['marca'];                   
    $other = $_POST['other'];                    
    $serial_number = $_POST['serial_number'];     
    $garantia = $_POST['garantia'];               
    $contrato = $_POST['contrato'];             
    $permissoes = $_POST['permissoes'];           
    $descricao_avaria = $_POST['descricao_avaria'];
    $checkbox = $_POST["checkbox"];
    $radio = $_POST["radio"];

 // Parse/Format/Verify Data
       $to      = "teste@teste.pt, $email"; 
       $from    = "Suporte";
       $subject = "Formulário de Suporte";

       $email_body = "$crlf De: $nome$crlf Email: $email$crlf Assunto: $subject$crlf$crlf Empresa: $empresa$crlf Contacto: $contacto$crlf Marca: $marca$crlf Outra: $other$crlf Número de Série: $serial_number$crlf Garantia: $radio$crlf Contrato: $checkbox$crlf Tipo de Suporte: $permissoes$crlf$crlf Descrição da Avaria: $descricao_avaria";

       // Setup EMAIL headers, particularly to support UTF-8
       // We set the EMAIL headers here, these will be sent out with your message
       // for the receiving email client to use.
       $headers ='From: '.$to . $crlf . 
                  'Reply-To: ' .$to  . $crlf . 
                  'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' .  $crlf .
                  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();



       // Then we pass the headers into our mail function
       mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);
       header('Location: agradecimentos.html');
?>
```

> **P.S:** Garantia é um radio button e Contrato é uma checkbox.
>   Caso vejam mais alguma parte do código errada, digam-me pfv. Desde já, muito obrigada

Comment: Adicione o html de dentro `<form>` completo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já adicionei o restante código do <form>

Comment: Pelo que entendi o `suporte_email.php` não está recebendo os dados, é isso? Já tentou colocar o `method` do formulário com *post* maiúsculo?